# Does the compiler provides extra stack space for byte-spilling?

Tags: compiler-construction, disassembly

From the sample code below which I got [here](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-12-16-disassembling-the-assembly-part-1.html), I don't understand why the value of registers are move to specific part in stack when byte-spilling is performed.

```
        pushq        %rbp
        movq        %rsp, %rbp
        subq        $96, %rsp
        leaq        L__unnamed_cfstring_23(%rip), %rax
        leaq        L__unnamed_cfstring_26(%rip), %rcx
        movl        $42, %edx
        leaq        l_objc_msgSend_fixup_alloc(%rip), %r8
        movl        $0, -4(%rbp)
        movl        %edi, -8(%rbp)
        movq        %rsi, -16(%rbp)
        movq        %rax, -48(%rbp)         ## 8-byte Spill
        movq        %rcx, -56(%rbp)         ## 8-byte Spill
        movq        %r8, -64(%rbp)          ## 8-byte Spill
        movl        %edx, -68(%rbp)         ## 4-byte Spill
        callq        _objc_autoreleasePoolPush
        movq        L_OBJC_CLASSLIST_REFERENCES_$_(%rip), %rcx
        movq        %rcx, %rdi
        movq        -64(%rbp), %rsi         ## 8-byte Reload
        movq        %rax, -80(%rbp)         ## 8-byte Spill
        callq        *l_objc_msgSend_fixup_alloc(%rip)
        movq        L_OBJC_SELECTOR_REFERENCES_27(%rip), %rsi
        movq        %rax, %rdi
        movq        -56(%rbp), %rdx         ## 8-byte Reload
        movl        -68(%rbp), %ecx         ## 4-byte Reload
```

And also, I don't know what is the purpose of byte-spilling since the program logic can still be achieved if the function is the one saving the value of the registers it will be used inside it.

I really have no idea why is this happening. Please help me understand this.

Comment: To someone how added obj-c tag, I don't mean specifically objective-c. I just get the code from a site which happens to be assembly version of objective-c. I saw other example assembly codes with `#-byte Spill` not from obj-c.

Comment: That looks like unoptimized code.  Try recompiling with the optimizer set to -Os

Comment: I want to know the purpose of byte-spilling and also I'm curious what's happening to the stack when byte-spilling code is present.

Comment: The purpose of spilling registers is to make the register available for another use, when the compiler has run out of them. Why this particular compiler is spilling these particular registers at this particular time in this particular program isn't really answerable in any more detail than that.

Comment: @EJP, thanks for the answer about byte-spilling. :) Is the stack adjusted for the byte-spilling? It seems it's providing space for byte-spilling but I'm not sure. It makes sense if it provides space.

Comment: Of course it's adjusted. The compiler needs a temporary, and it comes from the stack. Stack space doesn't appear out of nowhere. It's not at all clear what you're really asking here, if you already know what spilling is.

Comment: I want to confirm if it's really adding extra space on stack. The day I posted this is the 1st time I encountered byte-spilling concept. And I am not yet good reading assembly language and have only little knowledge how compiler converts C/C++ syntax to machine instructions. I also want to know the reason why the compiler produces so much byte-spilling code(in debug mode) even though it's not necessary. I believe there are good reason why they do that.

Comment: Also, almost everytime I'm creating a function, I keep the stack small by reusing some variables and/or surrounding some group of codes inside curly brackets. It feels a bit unfair when I discovered the compiler is wasting stack space. :p